# What type of milk is used together with whole grain cereal?

Tags: milk

Currently, I am using condensed milk together with whole grain cereal. So, I was wondering if it is possible to use other type of milk - such as low-fat milk powder and cook it together with whole grain cereal?

Please note that I have not heard of people using milk powder and cook together with whole grain cereal and so was wondering if there are people out there using milk powder together with whole grain cereal and cook together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, every morning when bacon is not on the menu

- One cup of whole grain cereal (muesli: rolled oats, flax seed, sunflower seed, Brazil nuts, walnuts, almonds, and some dried fruits for extra flavour, all finely dices in food processor)
- One generous table spoon of whole milk powder (New Zealand grass feed cows please)
- Water to cover
- Nukulate** for 3 minutes on high
- Stir and let stand for a minute or two

Enjoy!

** *Use Microwave oven if you don't have your own Thermonuclear generator*

Comment: Please define "Nukulate" http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91250/what-does-nukulate-mean

Comment: Westinghouse are selling them to China!

Comment: @TFD, I could not find the Thermonuclear generator in the http://www.westinghouse.com/. Am I missing out something?

Comment: @Jack http://www.westinghousenuclear.com/, or more specifically http://ap1000.westinghousenuclear.com/

Comment: @TFD, Oh gosh! I thought its size is sort of like a electrical oven but never thought that it is actually a building itself.

Comment: @Jack, NASA make small, portable thermonuclear generators using Pu or Th, but they aren't for sale, and I think they kill you if you get near them. They send them to Mars!